# Using Python script to check my network devices connectivity

Tags: python, oop

I have written below a Python script to check my network device's connectivity. it is working properly but still, I want to use it with the OOPS feature of python. Using OOPS failed to work. For your reference, I have pasted the code below.

```py
    import os
    from termcolor import colored
    import threading
    import time
    
    
    class Connectivity:
    
        def __init__(self,aph, ip, count):
            self.aph = aph
            self.ip = ip
            self.count = count
    
        def pingPong(self):
            rqst = os.popen(f"ping {self.ip} -n 4").read()
            if 'Request timed out.' in rqst:
                print("Testing Connectivity To AP ---->" + colored(self.aph, 'blue', attrs=['bold']) +
                      " & IP Address: " + colored([self.ip], 'cyan', attrs=['bold']) + " & This AP count is: "
                      + colored(self.count, 'magenta', attrs=['bold']))
                print(colored(rqst, 'red', attrs=['bold']))
                opt = open("output.text", 'a')
                opt.write(str(self.aph) + '\t' + str(self.ip) + '\t' + 'Down' + '\n')
                opt.close()
            elif 'Destination host unreachable.' in rqst:
                print("Testing Connectivity To AP ---->" + colored(self.aph, 'blue', attrs=['bold']) +
                      " & IP Address: " + colored([self.ip], 'cyan', attrs=['bold']) + " & This AP count is: "
                      + colored(self.count, 'magenta', attrs=['bold']))
                print(colored(rqst, 'orange', attrs=['bold']))
                opt = open("output.text", 'a')
                opt.write(str(self.aph) + '\t' + str(self.ip) + '\t' + 'Down' + '\n')
                opt.close()
            else:
                print("Testing Connectivity To AP ---->" + colored(self.aph, 'blue', attrs=['bold']) +
                      " & IP Address: " + colored([self.ip], 'cyan', attrs=['bold']) + " & This AP count is: "
                      + colored(self.count, 'magenta', attrs=['bold']))
                print(colored(rqst.upper(), 'green', attrs=['bold']))
                opt = open("output.text", 'a')
                opt.write(str(self.aph) + '\t' + str(self.ip) + '\t' + 'Up' + '\n')
                opt.close()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pingap = Connectivity()
        pingap.pingPong()
        st = time.perf_counter()
        count = 0
        filnm = str(input("Please enter file name which content hostname and ip address: "))
        with open(filnm, 'r') as rf:
            nw = rf.read()
            nw1 = nw.splitlines()
        thread1 = list()
        for ap in nw1:
            aph = ap.split()[0]
            ip = ap.split()[1]
            count += 1
            th = threading.Thread(target=pingap.pingPong(), args=(aph, ip, count))
            thread1.append(th)
    
        for th in thread1:
            th.start()
    
        for th in thread1:
            th.join()
    
        with open('output.text', 'r') as see:
            wach = see.read()
            udps = wach.splitlines()
        print("\n")
        print("*" * 50)
        print("\nDevices are Online \n")
        for ud in udps:
            udvs = ud.split()[0]
            dip = ud.split()[1]
            up = ud.split()[2]
            if "Up" in up:
                print(colored(udvs, 'yellow') + " " + colored(dip, 'cyan') + ' is ' + colored(up, 'green',
                                                                                              attrs=['bold']))
        print("\n")
        print("*" * 50)
        print("\nDevices are Offline \n")
        for ud in udps:
            ddvs = ud.split()[0]
            dip = ud.split()[1]
            dwn = ud.split()[2]
            if "Down" in dwn:
                print(colored(ddvs, 'yellow') + " " + colored(dip, 'cyan') + ' is ' + colored(dwn, 'red',
                                                                                              attrs=['bold']))
    
        et = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"Total time execution this script is {round(et - st, 2)} seconds(s)")
```

I have run this code using OOPS but it is repeating the same IP address, which should not be done. I hope you can understand my query. Here I am not expecting a full solution If possible give me short clue to fix this issue.

Comment: Show us your observed and expected output!

Comment: Python code without OOPs working fine.